# VSCode Intellisense weird autocompletion on Javascript code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I just ran into some strange behavior using VSCode writing a JS file.

[image]

See that I'm trying to access the `hasOwnProperty()` method on the fluffy object. And VSCode didn't autocomplete or suggest anything on my line of code.

**At this point I'm already thinking that I'm doing something wrong and that I'm probably not able to access this method through my object.**

But the interesting thing is:

[image]

**QUESTION:**

As soon as a finish typing hasOwnProperty and I open the parenthesis, VSCode triggers the IntelliSense and recognizes the method. Is it normal? How come VSCode doesn't show me all the properties and methods available to my object since the first letter that I've typed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**VSCode About:**
Version: 1.25.1
Date: 2018-07-11T15:43:53.668Z
Electron: 1.7.12
Chrome: 58.0.3029.110
Node.js: 7.9.0
V8: 5.8.283.38
Architecture: x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected. We don't show intellisense suggestions for `Object.prototype` properties because they would show up on pretty much every object and are therefore not very useful. However the language smarts do know that `hasOwnProperty` exists, which is why you get signature help for it

Comment: The same reason for 'array.length'? But WebStorm will autocomplete this, why?

Comment: No, `.length` is suggested on arrays