# Object.prototype hints in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, hints

I use **Visual Studio Code** to **JavaScript** programming. And when I create some simple object, I want to see the hints about properties of it's prototype.

```
let o = {};
```

I want to use method from it's prototype (*Object.prototype*), but there are no hints about this. If my object has some own properties, I see just these properties. With another structures hints are shown:

```
let a = [];
```

When I input "a." I see all properties from *Array.prototype*. The only way to see properties of Object.prototype is to create object via "new Object()":

```
let o = new Object();
```

And now after inputing "o." I see the properties. But for me it is unconfortable and also if I use "new Object()" I can't see hints about object's own properties:

```
let o = new Object();
o.myProp = 'I want to see hint about this property...';
```

Now after inputing "o." I see just properties from *Object.prototype*, but don't see "myProp". Is it possible to enable hints about properties of *Object.prototype* for all objects, whose inheritance chain includes *Object.prototype*?

Comment: Yep, same behavior here. Looks like a deliberateVSCode limitation, though I'm surprised `new Object` works https://stackoverflow.com/q/51895461 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54944

Comment: But maybe some plugins, which can enable this feature, exists?